# how can I get nth digit in a BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

I was working on some `BigInteger` problems where the size of each number is 2^100. And I need the nth digit of that number How do I do that?

Using `toString()` I converted that BigInteger in String then get that digit
But the size of the String is Upto only the max value of Int?

```
int get(BigInteger b,BigInteger n)
{
  return Character.getNumericValue(b.toString().charAt(n.intValue()));
}
```

So this code works only when the BigInteger is less than Int max value.
But In my case after certain iterations, It might be the chance my BigInteger cross that Limits so how can get nth BigInteger digit in that BigInteger?

Comment: How did you get the idea that the string would only represent numbers up to the max value of Int? Or do you mean you have more than 2 billion digits?

Comment: Can’t reproduce your problem. Can you post the complete code? This works:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigIntString {
    static int get(BigInteger b, BigInteger n) {
 return Character.getNumericValue(b.toString().charAt(n.intValue()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 BigInteger big = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
 big = big.multiply(big).multiply(big).multiply(big).multiply(big).multiply(big).multiply(big);
 System.out.println(big.toString());
 int i = get(big, BigInteger.valueOf(5));
 System.out.println(i);
    }
}```

Comment: Consider a scenario like this. ` BigInteger b = factorial(10000);
        System.out.println(b.toString().charAt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)); `

Comment: factorial(10000) has less than 40000 digits which is way below Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Or is `BigInteger n` the problem? Really more than 2 billion digits? String is backed up by an array of chars (if i understood the docs), and the index of an array can only be an int, not a long. So you are lost ;-) You would have to write your own toVeryLongString() method, starting with the binary representation.

Comment: if StringIndexOutOfBoundsException has thrown if the value exceeds than 2147483647.

Comment: can we use Stream to go after that limit ?

Comment: I have the impression you are looking for the solution to a problem you do not have.

Comment: You are completely confused by the difference between a BigInteger and the number of digits in a BigInteger. The number of digits is proportional to *the log* of the BigInteger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using BigInteger#toString and use charAt(int i) ... I wrote a Test for you:

```
@Test
void testBigInt(){
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("123456789012345678901234567890");
    System.out.println(bi.toString().charAt(25));
}
```

When running, I get a "6" printed... which seems right

when your position Integer, which you use in "charAt()" is too big (bigger than maxIntValue) then you will need to modulo and divide your original BigInteger

you can "cut off" the first and last numbers and only look at the range you are interested in

```
    @Test
public void testIt() {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("1234567890");
    BigInteger resDiv = bi.divide(new BigInteger("100000"));
    System.out.println(resDiv.toString());
    BigInteger resMod = resDiv.mod(new BigInteger("1234"));

    System.out.println(resMod.toString());

}
```

Comment: I know that and I mentioned that in my code. charAt only works upto the integer max value after that it throws an exception.

Comment: @AashishPawar  Not it doesn't.  It represents an `index` of that size.  You would only have problems if your String was larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  So does you number have more than 2 billion digits? (as was previously asked).

Comment: ohhh... now I understand... charAt(Integer.maxValue() + 1)

Comment: BTW, the number of digits `base 10` of `2^100` is only about `100/3.2` so you shouldn't have any problems using the supplied solution.

Comment: BigInteger b = factorial(10000);
System.out.println(b.toString().charAt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));  it throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2147483647

Comment: you need to cut out the section you are interested in, without loosing information... I updated my answer - you need to make it dynamic

Comment: (dont forget the edge case with negative values)